SSLによるオレオレ認証局、ワイルドカード指定証明書でホスト名が一致しないとのエラーが発生する
プライベートネットワークにリバースプロキシの構築を検討、それに先立ち
以下リンクに沿ってプライベート認証局及びnginxでwebサーバを構築しましたが、
ブラウザでエラーが発生してしまいます。
https://pvision.jp/tech/2023/05/web-server-https-support-by-private-ca/#google_vignette
https://pvision.jp/tech/2024/03/install-nginx-with-https/
前提としてプライベートDNSが構築してあり、*.internalドメインで名前解決ができています。
<Chrome https://www.internal>
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: *.internal
Issuer: Private Root CA
curl -vvs https://www.internal
*   Trying 192.168.0.2:443...
* Connected to www.internal (192.168.0.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=JP; O=Private; CN=*.internal
*  start date: Jun 21 05:17:13 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 21 05:17:13 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match www.internal
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.internal'
* Closing connection 0

CNにwww.internal、SANにwww.internalを指定すると正常に動作しますが、
ワイルドカード(*.internal)を指定すると上記エラーが発生します。
どこに問題があるか教えていただけませんでしょうか？

CN=*.internal は相手にしてなくて、subjectAltNameで検証しています。
subjectAltNameにDNSName = *.internalを設定しましょう。


openssl req -new -key ../out/web-server.key -out web-server.csr -addext "subjectAltName=*.internal"

subjectAltNameの書式が間違っています。
openssl-reqによると
openssl req -new -subj "/C=GB/CN=foo" \
                 -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:foo.co.uk" \
                 -addext "certificatePolicies = 1.2.3.4" \
                 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out req.pem

という形式で書きます。

sayuriさま
ご回答ありがとうございます！説明に不備があり申し訳ありません。
SANにも*.internalを設定しておりますがエラーが発生してしまいます。
openssl req -new -key ../out/web-server.key -out web-server.csr -addext "subjectAltName=*.internal"

subjectAltName="DNS:*.internal"の誤りでした。

@tamanegi コメントで適当なことを書かず、質問文を編集してください。
